# Flash Actionscript3: How to reset datagrid between frames

Tags: actionscript-3, datagrid, flash-cs5.5

I use ActionScript3 in Flash Professional to build an animation in multiple frames.

The user has forward and back buttons to navigate between frames. At a certain time, I introduce a datagrid (inserted from the editor) fill it with data and everything goes OK.

```
//Example frame 9

stop();

r7.removeAllColumns()

r7.addColumn("column1");
r7.addColumn("column2");
r7.addColumn("column3");

r7.addItem({column1:"A", "column2":"a1", "comumn3":"1"});
r7.addItem({column1:"B", "column2":"b1", "comumn3":"1"});
```

But each time the user goes back to the previous frame (frame 9) from (frame 10), the datagrid is refilled with the same rows again.
I used **removeAllColumns()** because without it, the same columns are appended to the existing ones.

Still the issues of rows not solved.

Here is the illustration:

#### frame9 from frame8:

[image]

#### frame9 from frame10:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Neither **removeAll()** alone nor **removeAllColumns()** alone will work.

- **removeAllColumns()**: removes columns (obvious).
- **removeAll()**: removes only rows, which is not obvious according to
  documentation.

This is what solved my issue:

```
r7.removeAll();
r7.removeAllColumns();
```

Here is the tests:
**1- Using only "removeAll()"**
[image]

**2- Using only "removeAllColumns()"**
[image]

**3- Using both "removeAll()" & "removeAllColumns()"**
[image]